# Could you please return tags pertaining to the question when the api's "answers on user" endpoint is called?

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.2

When I call "answers on users", I see that I can select a filter named "tags".

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users#page=1&pagesize=5&order=desc&sort=votes&ids=303685&filter=!3yXvhBHgyv6O(7ctT&site=stackoverflow&run=true

However, the response for this endpoint does not return the tags, arguably because answers do not have tags. However, it would be useful to return the tags associated with the question, which this is an answer of, in the `tags` array in the response.

Otherwise, to get the tags associated with (the question associated with) an answer, I'll need to make 2 API calls -- the first to "answers on users" and then to "question/id" to get the tags associated with the question.

Could you please either return the tags in the `tags` array or may be designate an additional array in the response named `question_tags`?